# import data from mysql database into existing html5 table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a database, and am trying to import into a table on my webpage, have found a few examples but they seem to always want to create the  table, whereas my webpage already has the table. Would I be right in thinking I need to utilise ajax in some way?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Are you talking about an **HTML** table? Like, you have a `<table>` element and you want to put data into it? Or are you talking about import data into a MySQL table, server-side, like from a CSV file? If the former (HTML table) then you really should use "render" instead of "import", which definitely suggests a server-side import of data into a database.

Comment: Yes, you would need to utilize AJAX.

Comment: the table I am trying to load is indeed an html table which resides on my website and already contains data which needs replacing with data I obtain from my database

Answer (score 1):

You could use JQuery for AJAX requests and update your HTML table with new data from Ajax response.
[JQuery get function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Answer (score 0):

You could echo your html5 table using php and that way you would be able to insert  php variables. You would use MYSQL SELECT and Php mysql_fetch_array() to get these values from your Mysql table and then set them as php variables that you would then echo in your table.
If you need example code please ask.

```
            $dbhost='/*hostname*/';
    $dbuser='/*database name*/';
    $dbpass='/*database password*/';
    $con=mysql_connect($dbhost , $dbuser , $dbpass);
    if (! $con)
    {
    echo 'Could not CONNECT';
    }
    echo '';
    mysql_select_db('/*user name*/');
            echo '<table>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$firstname.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$secondname.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</table>';
            $firstnameq="SELECT firstname FROM /*table*/";
            $secondnameq="SELECT secondname FROM /*table*/":
            $firstname=mysql_fetch_array($firstnameq);
            $secondname=mysql_fetch_array($secondnameq);
```

Comment: example code would be most gratifying, Thank You